# how to find out the users added to a role in postgresql ?

Tags: postgresql

I am working on postgresql ver 9.4.5. I am adding users to super user role(master) as below:

```
grant testuser1 to master;
grant testuser2 to master;
```

Now how to find out the list of users added to this role "master".Is there any specific system tables/views to query this ?  I need to pass the role name 'maser' in the where clause.

Many Thanks

Comment: maybe this give you and idea to start http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56096/how-to-get-all-roles-that-a-user-is-a-member-of-including-inherited-roles

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and belwo query shows result correctly. Could someone confirm whether this query is correct ?

```
testdb= #grant testuser1 to master;
GRANT ROLE

testdb= #grant testuser2 to master;
GRANT ROLE

testdb= #grant testuser3 to master;
GRANT ROLE

SELECT rolname FROM pg_roles WHERE
   pg_has_role( 'master', oid, 'member')
and rolname not in ( 'master')

    rolname
----------------
 testuser1 
 testuser2
 testuser3
(3 rows)
```

Many Thanks,